# Autodesk Forge Data Management API Resumable Upload fail on files over 2GB

Tags: autodesk-forge

When uploading very large files over 2GB I am receiving the error;

> (416) Requested Range Not Satisfiable.

I was encountering it with .Net API so I tried it with the REST API and I get the same error there. This makes me think that the Forge filesystem may be 32bit which doesn't support files larger than 2GB or maybe the REST API code for resumable defines the range values as int and can't handle a value greater than 2147483648. I've looked for a max file-size limit in the documentation but didn't find one.

Has anyone else encountered this problem or better yet, found a way around it? My file is already zipped so that's not a solution in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doh, I found the issue. I was on the right track with the code using an int rather than a long, but it was my code at fault. I would have expected an error when an int gets set to a value exceeding it's max value but that isn't the case so when the range string was calculated I ended up with;

> bytes 2139095040-**-2124414977**/3221225472

when I was expecting;

> bytes 2139095040-2170552319/3221225472

I suspect the C# code I was updating came from a sample somewhere on the internet so I guess it's worth leaving this question and answer in place, hopefully it will help someone else that runs into the same issue.

Comment: Good catch. I'm wondering - if you're using a resumable upload already, why uploading the file in chunks of **2GB**? Doesn't that kinda defeat the purpose of resumable upload?

Comment: I just wish I had caught it before submitting the question. In the example byte range shown above, I'm uploading a 3GB file in chunks of 30MB. The chunk starts at byte 2139095040 and ends at byte 2170552319 from a total of 3221225472 bytes in the file.  Chunks of 30MB are pretty big but they're being sent from Azure so a 30MB chunk only takes about 5 seconds to upload to Forge. You're right though that using resumable if there was only one chunk wouldn't make sense.